# JQuery get specific attribute from li

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following problem. I have an asp gridview with an unordered list on each line.
Each list is sortable and connected to drag items between the lists.
However I am not able to get the values of these lists.

I have tried with the below function:

```
var routedQuestions = $(this).find("#sortable2").map(function (i, n) {
                return $(n).attr('value');
            }).get().join(',');
```

As well as:

```
var routedQuestions = $(this).find("#sortable2").sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'value' });
```

This worked when I first added an item to the list, but not if there was already an item in the list.

Any idea where I am going wrong here? 
I have not been able to find a solution online yet.

---

EDIT:

The actual script for the page is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvQuestionnaireRouting" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CssClass="table table-striped table-hover"
            DataKeyNames="QuestionnaireID" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
            GridLines="None" ClientIDMode="Static">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnQuestionnaireID" Value='<%# Bind("QuestionnaireID") %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuestionText") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Routed Questions">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue" runat="server">
            </ul>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

The listItems are being generated at run time and are as follows:

```
<li value="1">Some text</li>
```

---

The whole save function for clarity:

```
function SaveAll() {
        $("#<%=gvQuestionnaireRouting.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").each(function() {
            //var routedQuestions = $(this).find("#sortable2").sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'value' });
            var routedQuestions = $(this).find("#sortable2").map(function (i, n) {
                return $(n).attr('value');
            }).get().join(',');
            var ParentID = $(this).find('input[id$=ParentQuestionElementID]').val();

            $(this).find("#sortable2 li").each(function () {
                var routingRule = $(this).find("#ddlRoutingRule").val();
                var routingValue = $(this).find("#txtRoutingValue").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "AdminRouting.aspx/SaveData",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: "{'routedQuestions':'" + routedQuestions + "','routingRule':'" + routingRule + "','routingValue':'" + routingValue + "','ParentID': '" + ParentID + "'}",
                    datatype: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    }

                });
            });

        });
    }
```

---

Edit:

Well after looking around more this seemed to do it:

```
var questionList = [];
            var routedQuestions = $(this).find("#sortable2 li");
            routedQuestions.each(function (idx, li) {
                questionList.push($(this).attr('value'));
            });
```

It might be a bit more of a dirty way to do it but it does work.

Comment: You should replicate your issue on jsfiddle and provide more context in your question. How do you call this code? And as IDs must be unique on document context, why not just: `var routedQuestions = $('#sortable2').val();` ??? If you have duplicate IDs like suggested by your code, then your HTML is invalid

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: I have updated my question with the html from the page.

Answer (score 0):

if you use from gridview you Should try that use from `Live()`  in your js for work with gridview.